# Ubuntu 12.10 Boots to a Black Screen - Intel HD Graphics

Tags: 12.10, boot, graphics, screen

I am a new to linux. I have an HP Pavilion DM4-1160US laptop. It has only one video card built-in (Intel HD), however Ubuntu seems to have a hard time with it.

It started when I tried to boot from a LiveCD - it booted into a black screen. Once I changed it "acpi=off" it booted up fine. I then installed Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit  (wiping the HDD), however when I rebooted it was to a black screen again.

I did some research, noticed that my graphics show as "unknown" and installed mesa-tools through apt-get. It then showed my graphics to be "Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2" but whenever I reboot it would again boot to a black screen. I tried installing (I think this is right) SNA from xorg but it still would not work.

I really want to get linux on my laptop but I am kind of at a loss here.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Chroot system from Ubuntu Live CD and in terminal type:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
sudo fdisk -l
Find root partition (example: /dev/sda1).
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ubuntu
sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/ubuntu/proc
sudo mount -t sysfs sysfs /mnt/ubuntu/sys
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/ubuntu/dev
sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/ubuntu/dev/pts
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/ubuntu/etc
sudo chroot /mnt/ubuntu
```

Add to GRUB2 configuration file nomodeset flag. [How to do this is here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

If that does not help, I recommend switching to a more stable version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: well, I did as suggested and nothing works. I even tried going to 12.04 LTS and same issue there. nomodeset does not work for me (same black screen) but "acpi=off" does. Any ideas?